# How to clean this Git history and prevent it to happen again

Tags: git

Here is what the git tree looks like:
[Git tree from GitX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUHdY.png)

The current workflow I use is:

1. Work and commit on the `develop` branch
2. When done with changes: `git checkout master`, `git merge develop -m "Merge message"`
3. Create the webpack build
4. Commit it and push: `git add .`, `git push origin master`
5. Repeat

This lead to this nasty history above while I was expecting only 2 branches.

Questions: 
How can I clean this ? 
How can I prevent this from happening again ?

Comment: can you show what branch names gitx gives for all those branches?

Comment: @njzk2 as far as I can tell they dont have name. In the "branches" tree of GitX I only have the main branches, `master`, `develop` and a few others

Comment: If you want to avoid those nasty merge commits, then consider using rebasing instead of merging.

Comment: ok. but where do they come from? can you show an example with how you get those branches separated? Do you push your `develop` branch to origin?

Comment: The whole workflow that I use is contain in the 4 steps in my questions. I do not create any other branches. I dont understand how does GitX sees this as a branch, while it should just be a commit on the master branch.
I do push develop to origin

Answer (score 0):

You should merge back `master` into `develop` after you merge `develop` to `master` (after step 4). In other words you should always start development on top of the recent `master`. Currently your `develop` is always behind and real merge happens instead of simple fast-fowrard.

And I don't see any reason to use `develop` branch at all in your scenario. You could just use single `master` branch name.

Comment: I use the branch master only for build. The develop branch never contain build files to avoid conflicts.

Comment: @binaryCactus So, you have branches which always diverge - that's why you have such weird history. It's a bad practice.